# TmcHash in .tsproj required / useful?

Tags: twincat

When working in TwinCAT projects I found that sometimes there is only a change indicated in the TmcHash attribute.

[image: change of TmcHash attribute highlighted in source control]

Is this attribute required or can this hash in some way be deactivated?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can deactivate it. The TmcHash is probably used to check if the tmc file on the disk corresponds to the one saved in the tsproj file.